# is there any solution to fix this stuff?

Tags: python, directory

```
PS C:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde> python -u "c:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde\programs\i.py"

Enter a number: 45
Enter a number: 3
Enter a number: 4
Enter a number: done
Maximum is 45.0
Minimum is 3.0
```

```
PS C:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde> python i.py

C:\Users\Sigde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'i.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde> python i.py
C:\Users\Sigde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe: can't open file 'i.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
PS C:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde>
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: How do you expect someone to answer this giving no general information, no details and only unformatted logs?

Comment: What is there to solve? you can see from the top that the file isn't in the vscodde directory,

Answer (score 4):

You solve it by specifying the *correct location* for the Python file. Since, based on your run that works, it's in:

```
c:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde\programs
```

and your current directory, based on the Powershell prompt, is:

```
c:\Users\Sigde\Desktop\vscodde
```

you would therefore use:

```
python programs\i.py
```

Comment: ok i got it thank you so much